# Disable OWA on Ex2016 but leave EAS

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, activesync

For security reasons our company has decided to disable OWA (at least to the outside world), but would like to keep EAS (Activesync) available for syncing mobile devices.

Is this possible?  Both use HTTP so I don't see how to allow one but not the other (we have a simple firewall).

It would be ok to disable OWA for internal use as well.  Is it possible through IIS or ECP to disable OWA only?

Comment: By simply googling you get lots of answers on how to disable OWA, but keep EAS working. Didn't it cover your scenario?

Comment: Most of the google results show how to disable OWA access per mailbox.  Some show disabling HTTP access (which also blocks EAS).  By simply googling high level terms you have found solutions to the wrong question.  I'm asking about disabling OWA at the server level while leaving EAS operational.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge:

**1.** You could remove the external URL of the OWA VD in the EAC to block external access:
[image]

If you want to disable the OWA access for certain user, you could run the command "**Set-CASMailbox adam@contoso.com -OWAEnabled $false -PopEnabled $false**"(From **[Enable or disable Outlook on the web for a mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/enable-or-disable-outlook-web-app#use-exchange-online-powershell-to-enable-or-disable-outlook-on-the-web)**)

**2.** Or you could also perform another method(**IP Addresses and Domain Restrictions** Settings in the **IIS**) to limit external IP. Before that, you need add the server role “**IP and Domain Restrictions**” in the **Server Manager**:

[image]

After that, you could allow your internal server IP address or a specific IP address to access the OWA in the **IIS** by clicking **Add Allow Entry**, and then deny unspecified clients to access by clicking **Edit Feature Settings**:

[image]
[image]
[image]